# getText() on AutoCompleteTextView returns SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView with a MatrixCursor as an adapter. The AutoCompleteTextView  has a OnItemClickListener as follows:

```
public class AutoCompleteListClickListner implements OnItemClickListener
{
    private AutoCompleteTextView acView;

    public AutoCompleteListClickListner(AutoCompleteTextView view)
    {
        this.acView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        /* tv is the selected view in the dropdown */
        TextView tv = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(0);
        Log.d(AndroidLogTag, "Before:>>>>" + this.acView.getText().toString());
        this.acView.setText(tv.getText().toString());
        Log.d(AndroidLogTag, "After:>>>>" + this.acView.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

When an item is selected I see following in the log

```
10-14 00:34:37.893: DEBUG/MyApp(19151): Before:>>>>android.database.MatrixCursor@4643e388
10-14 00:34:37.912: DEBUG/MyApp(19151): After:>>>>Ankit V Jain
```

If you see the log, the `Before` log entry, the `getText()` returns a `SpannableStringBuilder` object and `toString()` of it returns some object identifier.

How do I get actual text of the auto-complete view which was there just before clicking drop-down item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is always another way (dirty or best) in code.

I added a `TextWatcher` to the AutoCompleteView and used `beforeTextChanged()` event to record text content and reuse that in `onItemClick()` !

Answer (score 0):

try casting `SpannableStringBuilder` to `CharSequence`